# Wrapping window global variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, woopra

I'm wrapping a global variable in a factory so that it can be injectable. It looks something like this:

```
angular.module('Analytics').factory('woopra', [
    '$window',
    function ($window) {
        return $window.woopra;
    }
]);
```

Because of how this tool works, at some point in the future after running initialisation, the variable `woopra` on the window gets replaced with a new value.

I need the injectable factory woopra to reference this new woopra variable that is on the window. What's a nice way to do this? At the moment I'm just referencing it as `$window.woopra` so I can mock `$window`.

Answer (score 0):

factory

```
angular.module('Analytics').factory('woopra', [function () {
  return {
    'injectableVar': 'test Value'
  }
}]);
```

Ctrl2

```
angular.module('Analytics').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'woopra', function ($scope, woopra) {
  woopra.injectableVar = 'Value from Ctrl1';
}]);
```

Ctrl2

```
angular.module('Analytics').controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', 'woopra', function ($scope, woopra) {
  $scope.Ctrl2Var = woopra.injectableVar;
}]);
```

This sample show enjectableVar share between 2 controller

Answer (score 0):

Why use factories? So much typing, I use the angular value and constant properties.  Use the constant one if you don't want it editable. And then just inject it into the controller you want to you:

```
app.constant("woopra", "test 1234");

// OR the value property, can also be an array

app.value("proptypes", [
{
    Description: "Duplex"
}, {
    Description: "Simplex"
}, {
    Description: "Duet"
}, {
    Description: "Cluster"
}, {
    Description: "House"
}, {
    Description: "Townhouse"
}]);
```